# Conditional Formatting based on column values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a column change color whenever a specific range within that same column has the same character, per example, I want cells C1:C50 to change to the color green when all the cells in C10:C50 have the value 1 on them.

I've tried this custom formula, that doesn't seem to work.

```
=C10:C50=CHAR(10004)
```

Sorry if this is an easy fix, but have been looking for answers and haven't found something that suits my problem

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you're after:

1. Select the rows you want the conditional format to apply to.
2. Click `format > conditional formatting`
3. Click `+ Add another rule`
4. Below "Format Rules" click the drop down and select `Is equal to`
5. Type what you want the box to be equal to in the input (for example, "1" in your case)
6. Click the "Done" button.
7. Behold your beautifully formatted sheet and the new found power that you wield!

Comment: This is not quite what I want, you see, doing that it will set my whole column with the desired color (which is what i want), even tho not all the cells in that range are equal 
 to 1

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTIF(C$10:C$50, CHAR(10004))=50
```

[image: 0]